# Sql Server 2005 Primary Key violation on an Identity column

Tags: sql-server, identity-column, primary-key

I’m running into an odd problem, and I need some help trying to figure it out.

I have a database which has an ID column (defined as int not null, Identity, starts at 1, increments by 1) in addition to all the application data columns. The primary key for the table is the ID column, no other components.

There is no set of data I can use as a "natural primary key" since the application has to allow for multiple submissions of the same data.

I have a stored procedure, which is the only way to add new records into the table (other than logging into the server directly as the db owner)

While QA was testing the application this morning, they to enter a new record into the database (using the application as it was intended, and as they have been doing for the last two weeks) and encountered a primary key violation on this table.

This is the same way I've been doing Primary Keys for about 10 years now, and have never run across this.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Or is this one of those cosmic ray glitches that shows up once in a long while.

Thanks for any advice you can give.

Nigel

Edited at 1:15PM EDT June 12th, to give more information

A simplified version of the schema...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Queries](
[QueryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[FirstName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[LastName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Address] [varchar](150) NOT NULL,
[Apt#] [varchar](10) NOT NULL
    ... <12 other columns deleted for brevity>
[VersionCode] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_Queries] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [QueryID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

(also removed  the default value statements)

The stored procedure is as follows

```
insert into dbo.tbl_Queries
    (   FirstName,
        LastName,
        [Address],
        [Apt#]...) values
    (   @firstName,
        @lastName,
        @address,
        isnull(@apt, ''), ... )
```

It doesn't even look at the identity column, doesn't use IDENTITY, @@scope_identity or anything similar, it's just a file and forget.

I am as confident as I can be that the identity value wasn't reset, and that no-one else is using direct database access to enter values.  The only time in this project that identity insert is used is in the initial database deployment to setup specific values in lookup tables.

The QA team tried again right after getting the error, and was able to submit a query successfully, and they have been trying since then to reproduce it, and haven't succeeded so far.

I really do appreciate the ideas folks.

Comment: Hmmm...any chance you can paste a sanitized table schema and/or the offending insert statement?

Comment: Are you still unable to add new records, or did it just occur once?

Comment: check out my answer below Nigel...

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like the identity seed got corrupted or reset somehow. Easiest solution will be to reset the seed to the current max value of the identity column:

```
DECLARE @nextid INT;
SET @nextid = (SELECT MAX([columnname]) FROM [tablename]);
DBCC CHECKIDENT ([tablename], RESEED, @nextid);
```

Comment: i didn't test my statement, so i rewrote it

Comment: I would second this one.  I don't see any way to duplicate values unless the seed has been rolled back.  I guess corruption could have happened but I've been using SQL for 10 years and have only seen corruption once in a low disk space scenario

Comment: Can be corrupted if identity_insert has been disabled somewhere, perhaps for development purpose, or an adminitrative task, copying from one database/table to another (various compare tools may mess it up if not careful). In a production environment it should hopefully not occur.

Comment: p.s. the above code, DBCC CHECKIDENT possibly needs the tablename in double quotes. The spec doesn't say that but examples use quotes. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms176057(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 4):

While I don't have an explanation as to a potential cause, it is certinaly possible to change the seed value of an identity column. If the seed were lowered to where the next value would already exist in the table, then that could certainly cause what you're seeing. Try running `DBCC CHECKIDENT (table_name)` and see what it gives you.

For more information, check out [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/datacenter/?p=406)

Comment: Yes, that was my first gut reaction, too - the table has probably been played around with and the IDENTITY value has been reset or something.

Comment: Or someone inserted values into the table with the SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON turn on.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I wasn't aware of that command, however, it didn't help.

It reported the current value as 550, and the column maximum value as 550, and that matches what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Random thought based on experience

Have you synched data with, say, Red Gate Data Compare. This has an option to reseed identity columns. It's caused issues for use. And another project last month.

You may also have explicitly loaded/synched IDs too.

Comment: Nope, this happened on a database setup specifically for QA about two weeks ago.

The database was deployed from VSTS Team Suite, 2008 edition, and populated with 500 generated records. Since then, they have added about 50 records both before and after the problem report.

Comment: Someone has either ran the DBCC CHECKIDENT or SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON then

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone insert some records logging into the server directly using a new ID explicity, then when the identity auto increment field reach this number a primary key violation happened.

But The cosmic ray is algo a good explanation ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just to make very, very sure...you aren't using an IDENTITY_INSERT in your stored procedure are you?  Some logic like this:

```
declare @id int;
Set @id=Select Max(IDColumn) From Sometable;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.SomeTable ON
Insert (IDColumn, ...others...) Values (@id+1, ...others...);
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.SomeTable OFF
.
.
.
```

I feel sticky just typing it.  But *every once in awhile* you run across folks that just never quite understood what an Identity column is all about and I want to make sure that this is ruled out. By the way: if this is the answer, I won't hold it against you if just delete the question and never admit that this was your problem!

Can you tell that I hire interns every summer?

Comment: Yep, I have checked, and there is no IDENTITY_INSERT in the stored procs.

The only place I found any was in the initial queries that get run to populate the lookup data (different tables than the one with the issue).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using functions like @@identity or scope_identity() in any of your procedures? if your table has triggers or multiple inserts you could be getting back the wrong identity value for the table you want

Comment: This would lead to data corruption, but not to a primary key violation in the table with the identity column, unless he's inserting explicit identity values.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully that is not the case, but there is a known bug in SQL 2005 with SCOPE_IDENTITY():
http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=328811

Answer (score 0):

The Primary Key violation is not necessarily coming from that table.

Does the application touch any other tables or call any other stored procedures for that function?  Are there any triggers on the table?  Or does the stored procedure itself use any other tables or stored procedures?

In particular, an Auditing table or trigger could cause this.

Comment: The error message we got from the server did specify that it was this table that was throwing the error.

The stored procedure doesn't touch any other tables, or call another stored procedure.

There is an update trigger, but the first thing it does is check to see if it is actually an update (i.e. the deleted pseudo table isn't empty).

I think I am going to chalk this up to cosmic rays (my manager agrees that since it isn't reproducible, we can ignore it unless it comes back).